# redirect author to his post after creating it and submitting its form with django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-views

i want to redirect the user to the post after creating it with django forms

in models.py

```
class Text(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    document = models.TextField(max_length=None, null=True)
    requirements = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

in my view.py

```
def text(request, pk):

    form = TextForm()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.save()
            text = Text.objects.get(id=pk)
            return redirect('text')

    text = Text.objects.get(id=pk)

    context = {'form': form, 'text': text}

    return render(request, 'main/text.html', context)
```

in my forms.py

```
class TextForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Text
        fields = ['title','document','requirements','deadline']
        widgets = {
            'title' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Title','class':'form-control m-2 mb-4 pb-2'}),
            'deadline' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Deadline','type':'date','class':'form-control m-2 pt-2',
            'id':'opendate'}),
            'requirements' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':ps_note,'class':'form-control col m-2','rows':'3'}),
            'document' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':ps_text,'class':'form-control'}),

        }
```

in my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('text/<str:pk>', views.text, name="text"),
    path('signin/', views.signin, name="signin"),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name="logout"),
]
```

i had to add this so stackoverflow accepts my question because it said that it's mostly code even after saying all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.urls import reverse

def text(request, pk):

    form = TextForm()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('text', args=[str(text.id)]))

    text = Text.objects.get(id=pk)

    context = {'form': form, 'text': text}

    return render(request, 'main/text.html', context)
```

Comment: it's now showing any errors but submitting forms stopped working i mean after i submit the form is not saved to the database

Comment: My bad, please change TextForm(request.POST) to TextForm(request.data).

Comment: it started saving them to the database , even with request.POST , but still not redirecting , if u have a solution please hook me up!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. The first involves setting your model's get_absolute_url() function. The other was just mentioned in another answer.
In your models.py file:

```
class Text(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    document = models.TextField(max_length=None, null=True)
    requirements = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/text/%i/" % self.id
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In your views.py file:

```
def text(request, pk):

    form = TextForm()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.save()
            text = Text.objects.get(id=pk)
            return redirect(text)

    text = Text.objects.get(id=pk)

    context = {'form': form, 'text': text}

    return render(request, 'main/text.html', context)
```

Comment: it didn't work! it kept adding the data to the database but not redirecting me to that post